# Why does synchronizing 1.4 TB of data with my Dropbox account result in over 28 TB of IO read?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sync, dropbox, io

I tried to sync 4.4 millions of files (totaling ~1.4 TB) with my Dropbox account. I noticed a pretty high amount of IO read (28 TB) when the files were being synchronized, is there any reason why?

[image]

My hard drive died at 28 TB so I don't know how much IO read synchronizing those files would have been done in the end.

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate, I have an [unlimited Dropbox for Business account](https://newsoffice.mit.edu/2014/ist-offers-dropbox-business-file-storage-sharing-mit-community-0821) and the late hard drive was a [Seagate Backup Plus 3TB Desktop External Hard Drive USB 3.0 (STCA3000101)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00829THQE).

Comment: Why did your hard drive die? Did you not have it plugged in, or did it have something to do with Dropbox? I assume the former, but I've had my hard drive freeze (not die, but still) when a lot of RAM was used during file compression (7z, that RAM hog).

Comment: @trysis The drive was plugged in: I launched some folder synchronization on Dropbox a few days ago, and came back today to see that the hard drive was dead. Room temperature and humidity were normal. Nobody touched the hard drive. No earthquake.

Comment: Strange. @TECHIE007 (that's probably not right) deduced that your hard drive was already failing. I guess he was right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the HDD actually died, then that's probably where the extra I/O comes from -- it retrying every bit it tried to read and/or write multiple times, because the drive was failing.

Comment: Thanks. Is the I/O read statistic in the Windows task manager the sum of failed I/O read and successful I/O read? I would have thought that only successful I/O read counted.

Comment: [See here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/what-task-manager-memory-columns-mean#1TC=windows-7): "The number of bytes read in input/output operations generated by the process, including file, network, and device I/Os."  So, for example, data sent form the OS to the drive and then rejected (triggering a retry by the OS) is still data sent, so it's recorded.  Can I prove that?  Not off-hand. ;)

Comment: Seagate hard drives with high storage to price ratio tend to fail more frequently than those made by Western Digital or Hitachi: https://www.backblaze.com/blog/hard-drive-reliability-update-september-2014/  If you value your data, do not buy Seagate Barracuda ever and perhaps stay away from other inexpensive Seagate hard drives with high storage volumes.